# React-redux useSelector state not working in onSubmit function but working in other functions

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, useselector

Please can someone explain to me why the second implementation of my code is reading the status_code of the msg and my first implementation can't read the status_code of the msg?

First implementation

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import InputField from '../components/layout/InputField';
import { faShop, faGlobe, faHouse, faSign, faMapLocationDot, faCity, faEarthEurope, faUpload } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import Button from '../components/layout/Button';
import FormAlert from '../components/layout/FormAlert';
import { createOrUpdateStore, clearMessages } from '../reducers/storeSlice';

const CreateStore = () => {
    const [formData, setFormData ] = useState({
        name: '',
        shop_url: '',
        house: '',
        street: '',
        postalcode: '',
        city: '',
        country: ''
    });

    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const { loading, store, msg, errors } = useSelector((state) => state.store);
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    
    const {
        name,
        shop_url,
        house,
        street,
        postalcode,
        city,
        country,
    } = formData;

    useEffect(() => {
        if (msg) {
            dispatch(clearMessages());
        }
    }, []);

    const onChange = (e) => {
        setFormData({ ...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    };

    const getError = (name) => {
        const findError = errors.filter(error => error.param === name);
        if (findErfind errorh > 0) {
            const error = errors.find(error => error.param === name);
            return error;
        }
    }

    const onSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const result = dispatch(createOrUpdateStore(formData));
        if (result) {
            if (msg.status_code === '201') {
                navigate('/login');
            }
        }
    }

    return (
        <form onSubmit={(e) => onSubmit(e)} className='dashboard-form'>
            <span className='header-text'>Create your store</span>
            {JSON.stringify(msg) !== '{}' ? (<FormAlert alert={msg} />) : ''}
            <InputField type='text' label='Store name' name='name' value={name} changeHandler={onChange} error={getError('name')} icon={faShop} />
            <InputField type='text' label='Website address' name='shop_url' value={shop_url} changeHandler={onChange} error={getError('shop_url')} icon={faGlobe} />
            <InputField type='text' label='House' name='house' value={house} changeHandler={onChange} error={getError('house')} icon={faHouse} />
            <InputField type='text' label='Street' name='street' value={street} changeHandler={onChange} error={getError('street')} icon={faSign} />
            <InputField type='text' label='Postalcode' name='postalcode' value={postalcode} changeHandler={onChange} error={getError('postalcode')} icon={faMapLocationDot} />
            <InputField type='text' label='City' name='city' value={city} changeHandler={onChange} error={getError('city')} icon={faCity} />
            <InputField type='text' label='Country' name='country' value={country} changeHandler={onChange} error={getError('country')} icon={faEarthEurope} />
            <Button text='CREATE' loading={loading} icon={faUpload} />
        </form>
    )
}

export default CreateStore;
```

Second implementation

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import InputField from '../components/layout/InputField';
import { faShop, faGlobe, faHouse, faSign, faMapLocationDot, faCity, faEarthEurope, faUpload } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import Button from '../components/layout/Button';
import FormAlert from '../components/layout/FormAlert';
import { createOrUpdateStore, clearMessages } from '../reducers/storeSlice';

const CreateStore = () => {
    const [formData, setFormData ] = useState({
        name: '',
        shop_url: '',
        house: '',
        street: '',
        postalcode: '',
        city: '',
        country: ''
    });

    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const { loading, store, msg, errors } = useSelector((state) => state.store);
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    
    const {
        name,
        shop_url,
        house,
        street,
        postalcode,
        city,
        country,
    } = formData;

    useEffect(() => {
        if (msg) {
            dispatch(clearMessages());
        }
    }, []);

    const onChange = (e) => {
        setFormData({ ...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    };

    const getError = (name) => {
        const findError = errors.filter(error => error.param === name);
        if (findError.length > 0) {
            const error = errors.find(error => error.param === name);
            return error;
        }
    }

    const onSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        dispatch(createOrUpdateStore(formData));
    }

    const redirectOnSuccess = (msg) => {
        if (msg.status_code === '201') {
            setTimeout(() => {
                dispatch(clearMessages());
            }, 2000);

            setTimeout(() => {
                dispatch(clearMessages());
                navigate('/store');
            }, 3000);
        }
    }

    redirectOnSuccess(msg);

    return (
        <form onSubmit={(e) => onSubmit(e)} className='dashboard-form'>
            <span className='header-text'>Create your store</span>
            {JSON.stringify(msg) !== '{}' ? (<FormAlert alert={msg} />) : ''}
            <InputField type='text' label='Store name' name='name' value={name} changeHandler={onChange} error={getError('name')} icon={faShop} />
            <InputField type='text' label='Website address' name='shop_url' value={shop_url} changeHandler={onChange} error={getError('shop_url')} icon={faGlobe} />
            <InputField type='text' label='House' name='house' value={house} changeHandler={onChange} error={getError('house')} icon={faHouse} />
            <InputField type='text' label='Street' name='street' value={street} changeHandler={onChange} error={getError('street')} icon={faSign} />
            <InputField type='text' label='Postalcode' name='postalcode' value={postalcode} changeHandler={onChange} error={getError('postalcode')} icon={faMapLocationDot} />
            <InputField type='text' label='City' name='city' value={city} changeHandler={onChange} error={getError('city')} icon={faCity} />
            <InputField type='text' label='Country' name='country' value={country} changeHandler={onChange} error={getError('country')} icon={faEarthEurope} />
            <Button text='CREATE' loading={loading} icon={faUpload} />
        </form>
    )
}

export default CreateStore;
```

I tried several methods for getting the msg in the onSubmit function but they didn't work. So I read the documentation of the react-redux toolkit and found out that you can use data gotten from the state with useSelector, and that you can use this data in any function but it still refused to work in the onSubmit() function. And this explains why the errors array was retrieved in the getError() function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issues

If I had to hazard a guess it is that the `createOrUpdateStore` is an asynchronous action that should be awaited, and there's a stale closure over the selected `msg` state in the `onSubmit` callback. The second implementation skips both these issues by not waiting for any returned Promises from `createOrUpdateStore` to resolve and relying on the `CreateStore` component to rerender when the redux state updates.

## Solution to fix implementation 1

Assuming this asynchronous `createOrUpdateStore` action returns a Promise it can be awaited. To overcome the stale `msg` closure the submit handler will need to manually access the store to get the current state.

```js
// declare submit handler async
const onSubmit = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  // await asynchronous action to resolve with result
  const result = await dispatch(createOrUpdateStore(formData));

  if (result) {
    // have result, get msg from current state
    const state = store.getState();
    const { msg } = state.store;
  
    if (msg.status_code === '201') {
      navigate('/login');
    }
  }
}
```

## Solution to fix implementation 2

The `redirectOnSuccess` function is called unconditionally as an unintentional side-effect and issues other unintentional side-effect. To make these ***intentional*** side-effects the logic should be moved into a `useEffect` hook with appropriate dependency.

```js
const {
  loading,
  store,
  msg,
  errors
} = useSelector((state) => state.store);
const navigate = useNavigate();

...

useEffect(() => {
  if (msg.status_code === '201') {
    dispatch(clearMessages());
    navigate('/store');
  }
}, [msg, navigate]);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your feedback. Initially, I was getting an error on my console when I added the "msg" and the "navigate" parameters to my useEffect dependencies. The error was saying "react-dom.development.js:27292 Uncaught Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops." on my browser console. That was why I stayed away from the useEffect implementation, but I tried your fix for implementation 2 and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a preventDefault to prevent the default submit action and it’s done by the code below:

```
Const onClick=(event)=>{
    event.preventDefault()
    // then you can have your redux function calls
}
```